# Adding Social Authentication to Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, social-authentication

I am using Django 3.0.5 and python 3.6. I want to add social authentication for my blog. Related files Settings.py, urls.py and login.html are:

Settings.py:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'social_django',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'social_core.backends.github.GithubOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')



EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from django.conf.urls import url,include
from blog import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('index/',views.index, name='index'),
    path('datetime/',views.current_datetime,name='datetime'),
    path('',views.post_list,name='post_list'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',views.post_detail,name="post_detail"),
    url('post_create/',views.post_create,name = "post_create"),
    url('login/', views.user_login,name="user_login"),
    url('logout/', views.user_logout,name="user_logout"),
    url('register/',views.register,name="register"),

    url('',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url(r'^oauth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace="social")),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

login.html:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
   <form method = "post">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{form.as_p}}


       <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-outline-success">

    <p> -- OR -- </p> 
    <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'github' %}">
        <button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Github </button>
    </a>  
    <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}">
        <button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-danger"> Google+ </button>
    </a>

    </form>   
{% endblock %}
```

In browser, when I click on Google+ button, I get the url "http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/login/google-oauth2/" from "http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/" but I supposed to get "401 error as invalid_client - The OAuth client was not found" because from this page's url, I get the value of uri which I need while doind setup django app on google developer console. Can anyone please help me how to get this error page ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using email login see settings you may have duplicated
`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`
Review Settings Good and make sure you only use it once and include all of the backends